# Android - How can one tell if db.execSQL was successful on onCreate

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sqlite

I have an xml file as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUOGI.png). I want two things, first, I want to insert pre-defined values in my sqlite database on onCreate method using an arraylist (or any method). Then secondly, I want to use those values from the arraylist, now in my database, to populate the two spinners(Producer and Product).

I have a database file that handles the db connections and methods and this is what I have done so far. This code is inside my onCreate method

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCT + "("
            + PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PRODUCER_FK + " INTEGER" + " FOREIGN KEY(PRODUCER_FK) REFERENCES TABLE_PRODUCER(PRODUCER_ID))");

            ContentValues contentv=new ContentValues();
            contentv.put("name", "Soya Seed");

            getWritableDatabase().insert("TABLE_PRODUCT", null, contentv);




    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCER + "("
            + PRODUCER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + PRODUCER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PRODUCER_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + PRODUCER_PHONE + " TEXT UNIQUE," + PRODUCER_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + CONTACT_PERSON  + " TEXT" + ")");

            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put("name", "ZamSEED");
            cv.put("address", "Luanda");
            cv.put("phone", "+244977654321");
            cv.put("email", "demo@zamseed.com");
            cv.put("contact_name", "Mr. Tembo");

            getWritableDatabase().insert("TABLE_PRODUCER", null, cv);
```

Then I have an inventory file that reads from the database to get values from the product and producers tables to populate the spinners.

My challenge is how can I tell if my db.execSQL is actually successful?
And how would I use an arraylist to insert values in the database?

NOTE: the app runs fine when I ran it but I am not sure if the tables are created and values inserted. Am a newbie to Android programming, thanks.

Comment: do you have rooted phone.. if yes then you can pull the db files and check .. path might be /data/data/<your_package_name>/databases/

Comment: no I don't have a rooted phone, is there a way of using a toast or something?

Answer (score 1):

After some time of research into this, I found this article [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper) that led me to see the actual tables of my db.execSQL command and the data contained. In `Ubuntu`:

```
 cd /path/to/my/sdk/platform-tools
 ./adb shell
 run-as <app package name>
 cd /data/data/<app package name>/databases
 ls
 chmod 666 <database file name>
 sqlite3 <database file name>
 > (semi-colon terminated commands can be run here to query the data)
 > .exit
 (copy full database path)
 exit
```

Then use sqlite3 commands to work on database `> (semi-colon terminated commands can be run here to query the data)`

Answer (score 0):

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public ArrayList<String>getProductList(){

   ArrayList<String>products = new ArrayList<String>();
   SQLiteDatabase qDB = getReadableDatabase();
   String columns[]=new String[]{PRODUCT_NAME};
   Cursor cursor = qDB.query(TABLE_PRODUCT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

   while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    String produectName = cursor.getString(1);
    products.add(productName);
    Log.e("e",products);
  }

 return products;
}
```

**SomeActivity.java**

```
spinnerProducts = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProducts);
ArrayList<String>productsList = new DatabaseHelper(context).getProductsList();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,productsList);
spinnerProducts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
...
//same logic for Producers list
```

Comment: where do I put my public ArrayList<String>getProductList() method? Inside my onCreate method?

Comment: thanks, it has made a difference, the Cursor is quite userful

Answer (score 0):

> My challenge is how can I tell if my db.execSQL is actually successful?

It was successful if it did not throw an exception.

However calling `getWritableDatabase()` in `onCreate()` is an error since that results in recursion: `getWritableDatabase()` triggers a call to `onCreate()` in the first place. You should use the `SQLiteDatabase` passed to you as a param instead.

If you did not see an exception about the recursive call then you already had a database file with the correct version. You can uninstall your app to clean up its data and then install and run it again to make `onCreate()` run again.

> And how would I use an arraylist to insert values in the database?

Use a loop to iterate the list and insert values one by one.

Comment: Thanks @laalto for your answer, I managed to find out though. Check my answer to this question